# Why does signalR reconnects get slower?

Tags: asp.net, performance, signalr

We are having reconnect timeouts on our servers. 
How should we debug this issue?

[image]

Comment: maybe this link can provide you with more information about this http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: As the link above should indicate, it isn't at all unexpected that signalr /reconnect, /connect and /poll requests last a long time. This is probably unrelated to your reconnect timeouts. In fact it's surprising that, on average, your /connect requests don't last longer. [Client-side logging](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging) might help you diagnose your issue.